# Constructor initialized by function return

Tags: c++, constructor, return-value

I cant follow why i cant initialize my class object in one line like below.
Getting VS errors which are not simple for me:

"error:E0334    class "example" has no suitable copy constructor"

and

"C2440  'initializing': cannot convert from 'example' to 'example'"

Some code:

```
class example {
public:
    example() { R = 0.F; I = 0.F; };
    example(float, float);
    example(example &);
    example sum( float, float);
private:
    float R, I;
};

example::example(float s1, float s2):R(s1), I(s2) {}

example::example(example & ex2) {
    R = ex2.R;
    I = ex2.I;
}

example example::sum(float s1, float s2){
    example s;
    s.R = s1;
    s.I = s2;
    return s;
}

int main() {
    float a = 2;
    float b = 4;
    example object1(1,1);
    example object2(object1.sum(a,b));
    return 0;
}
```

Why initializing `object2` like this:

```
example object2(object1.sum(a,b));
```

getting error, but something like this:

```
example object2;
object2 = (object1.sum(a,b));
```

pass without error, is it ok?

Comment: "C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from 'example' to 'example'"? `example` to `example`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Comment: @codekaizer that's Microsoft C++ ... the most vexing error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
example object2(object1.sum(a,b));
```

this is not copy constructor, this is move constructor because argument is rvalue.

so, you can add move constructor explicitly like this.

```
class example {
public:
    example() { R = 0.F; I = 0.F; };
    example(float, float);
    example(example &);
    //move
    example(example &&);
    example sum( float, float);
private:
    float R, I;
};

example::example(float s1, float s2):R(s1), I(s2) {}

example::example(example & ex2) {
    R = ex2.R;
    I = ex2.I;
}

example::example(example && ex2){
    R = ex2.R;
    I = ex2.I;
}

example example::sum(float s1, float s2){
    example s;
    s.R = s1;
    s.I = s2;
    return s;
}

int main() {
    float a = 2;
    float b = 4;
    example object1(1,1);
    example object2(object1.sum(a,b));
    return 0;
}
```

and this

```
example object2;
object2 = (object1.sum(a,b));
```

is ok because,it will call copy assignment operator that compiler generate automatically (when you add move constructor like me, compiler will not generate copy assignment operator)

Comment: Is it good if i only change from `example(example &);` to `example(example const &);` in my code?

Comment: As my opinion, move constructor is better because example::sum make object temporary. If example::sum return self, example(const example  &); is better.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `const` in the [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

```
example(example const &);
```

> Why initializing object2 like this:
>
> ```
> example object2(object1.sum(a,b));
> ```
>
> getting error

Because you can't get a non-const reference from the rvalue `object1.sum(a,b)`.

> but something like this:
>
> ```
> example object2;
> object2(object1.sum(a,b));
> ```
>
> is ok?

This code is also wrong, the second line would require an `operator ()`.

Comment: [Do you always need a const in copy constructor?](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy#ctor-1)

Comment: Yep. A const isn't required for a copy c'tor, but is necessary for it to be able to catch an rvalue reference (rvalues can be bound to const-lvalue references).

Comment: Now, I get it, but in second I've mean: `object2 = (object1.sum(a,b));` with this compilator passes without error.

Comment: @Mat3o `object2 = (object1.sum(a,b));` does not call copy constructor but [copy assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment).